# Why should one change the index name of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

Is there any advantage to using another name for the index of a pandas DataFrame/Series? If I use `df[index_name]`, it doesn't work. Pandas [docs on MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) has an example where the indices have names, but the names are not used at all in slicing or selecting data. If you're not printing the dataframe, what's the use of changing the index name?

Comment: Can you can use the index name in groupby statements, therefore making the code more readable.  IE.. df.groupby('IndexName')... vs df.groupby(level=1)...  And, there are some other statements that allow for using index name vs index level numbers, hence improving readability of the code.

Comment: @ScottBoston `df.groupby('IndexName')` would try to group on a column with `'IndexName'` but yes `df.groupby(level='IndexName')` would be the more readable form and perhaps a good use case for having named indices

Comment: @EdChum `df = df.set_index('id')`  `df.groupby('id')['value1'].sum()` does work.  In Pandas 0.23.0.

Comment: @ScottBoston hmm the docs seem to indicate that `by` should refer to columns, `A label or list of labels may be passed to group by the columns in self. ` interesting this works also with the index name

Comment: @EdChum this was a groupby enhancement update in Pandas 0.20.0  [see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-enhancements)

Comment: @ScottBoston ah right, the docs should be updated then

Answer (score 1):

There are scenarios where you create an index from a column. In these cases, in new versions of Pandas (i believe 0.22 and above), Pandas names the index the same as the column is was copied from. Then when you try to do something, the two can conflict and from what I can see in Pandas 0.24 you cannot manipulate a dataframe (i.e. sort_values('columnname_sameas_indexname'). Really quite a problem for me as I have many indices that are created from a column, and now that i updated to 0.24, my code fails (until I go rename all these damn indices...)